# NSApplicationLoad in a C header?

Tags: c, cocoa

I discovered that I had to call NSApplicationLoad in order to obtain display reconfiguration callbacks. My program is written in straight C, and for various reasons I'd like to avoid adding Objective-C code to my project.

The headers in which `NSApplicationLoad` is defined (either `Cocoa/Cocoa.h` or `AppKit/AppKit.h`) are Objective-C headers, and naturally throw lots of errors when compiled with a normal C compiler.

Calling `NSApplicationLoad` with a simple `extern void NSApplicationLoad(void)` prototype works, and indeed my program works fine. But, I'm somewhat worried that this is not a "proper" approach since it feels like I should be including something.

Is there a straight C header (like the CoreFoundation or ApplicationServices headers) which contains NSApplicationLoad? If not, is my current approach (to just apply the prototype) safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `NSApplicationLoad` in C function and call the wrapper function in your c code.

Wrapper.h

```
BOOL MyNSApplicationLoad(void);
```

Wrapper.m (need to be ObjC file to include ObjC header)

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
BOOL MyNSApplicationLoad(void) {
    return NSApplicationLoad();
}
```

some.c

```
#include "Wrapper.h"

void foo() {
   MyNSApplicationLoad();
}
```

so even when signature of `NSApplicationLoad` is changed in future release of SDK, you will get noticed and you only need to modify the wrapper function.

However it is very unlikely that `NSApplicationLoad` is ever going to be changed because it is a documented public API. Simply declare `BOOL NSApplicationLoad(void)` in one of your header file should be enough and safe.

---

and you may noticed, it is `BOOL NSApplicationLoad (void)` not  `void NSApplicationLoad(void)`